# If I change all automaic statup services to manual then at the time of need does the main software will start those manual setted services?

Tags: boot

Suppose I change the VMware authorization,VMware DHCP ,VMware NAT etc autostart services to manual start; Does starting the VMware Workstation will then start those services automatically?

Or, I have to manually start them prior to starting VMware ?!

Comment: @DonSimon I guess it would be more constructive and helpful for the OP if you could post an actual answer and explain how services really work.

Comment: -1 for not even trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is highly dependant on a couple of factors:

1. Whether the user is a high enough level user on the machine (thus having the ability to actually start services in the first place).  UAC may block anyone except "fully fledged" administrators.
2. Whether the program itself was written to detect the status of the service and, if need be, be able to start it.

I'm believe that being an administrator on the machine **is** necessary to start services as it is making potentially harmful changes to the computer.  Think about if a normal user (or program belonging to them) could stop and start the "Network" service without any control whatsoever.  It could quickly render your computer unusable or unstable or worse.

As that is the case it is possible that any program belonging to that user is not able to start a service even if it was so programmed to do, unless it has been started with administrator privileges as it will immediately be blocked by [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

What you as a user could do though is to use the [net start](http://ss64.com/nt/net_service.html) command.

You could simply write a simple batch file that runs the commands necessary to start or stop the VMWare services, then right click that batch file and select "Run as Administrator":

```
net start "VMware DHCP"
net start "VMware authorization"
net start "VMware NAT"
```

and so on. Then with another script, also using the "Run as Administrator":

```
net stop "VMware DHCP"
net stop "VMware authorization"
net stop "VMware NAT"
```

Assuming you have administrator rights, or at least the administrator password in which case the "Run as Administrator" will pop up a password prompt.

As a side note, there are [many, many ways](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html) to have a program run as administrator, most of which will pop up a UAC prompt.